# The maths behind the simultaneously falling objects with same shape and bigger mass than the other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, mass, acceleration, free-fall

Can you show me the maths behind this phenomena.
When two balls fall down in which one with bigger mass than the other and same shape, they both fall simultaneously.

Comment: 9.8=9.8 It's more of a conceptual thing than mathematical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a sort of "basic physics expectation" why this should happen, if you want to hear it.

Suppose an object of mass $2M$ fell faster than an object of mass $M$. Usually high-school students expect the first to fall, say, twice as fast, but it's not super-important what value it is.

Now imagine dropping two objects of mass $M$ side by side. They are both objects of mass $M$ so they both fall as fast as objects of mass $M$ do. But if they are "close enough" then they must fall like an object of mass $2M$ does. So we would have to find out that this change in speed only happens when they are "close enough", say closer than a distance $L$.

Now we know that phenomena like this happen, but they usually happen due to **wind resistance**, where both objects have to "drag" a boundary layer of air with them, but as they get closer both objects get to "share" this boundary layer and cooperate on dragging it at their speed, so they don't need to work so hard and they can fall a little faster.

But for *gravity* this does not seem to be our experience, we do not say "I couldn't jump so high because you were standing too close to me, stand back and I will try to jump again" or the like. It's our experience that gravity does not care how close you are to other objects however massive; you don't become more heavy when standing next to a wall than you are when standing in the middle of a room. So the only alternative is that gravity doesn't care about how close two things are to each other, and therefore that objects of mass $2M$ fall exactly like objects of mass $M$.

**Edit**: because the logic is apparently not 100% clear here, the argument is, "you get a great physical intuition by looking at what happens if you drop an object by itself, or you have two identical objects and you drop them next to each other, bringing them closer and closer together." If there is a reason for them to go faster as they get closer (like when you fall faster when skydiving in a cannonball shape than spreading your arms out to "catch" the air) then you have a situation where objects of different mass will fall differently. But if there is no such reason (like with two people jumping next to each other vs. across the room from each other) then objects of different mass must all fall following the same path.

Comment: I was going to answer this way but you beat me to it.

Comment: just to clarify things a lel bit what i seemed to understand and hopefully i followed up .. that  you mean that the air joined up formed a frame and contained both objects resisting it's motion downward so it's as if they both are one body this is why they both touch the ground at the same time ?

Comment: @CR Drost. Nice. That's also why they also said in the early writings that the acceleration is independent of shape. Note that the argument does not work out the same way for electrical charges in a uniform electric field, two close charges vs 1 with twice the charge. There is something special about mass

Comment: @ahmedelbarky Sorry, the exact opposite of that. **In the absence of air** they must fall at the same rate. Air can change that in two ways: first it creates a **buoyant force** which is why beach balls seem to "float" and helium balloons actually do; this obeys the above argument as long as the $2M$ arrangement has twice the total volume as each single-$M$ arrangement does, as when you bring the two objects next to each other and glue them together.

Comment: Second it creates a **drag force** which indeed depends on nearby fluid flow as well as cross sectional area and surface roughness; this is the **core thing** that changes when we drop a feather next to a big steel ball and observe "hey, the feather drops slower than the ball!"

Comment: And it is the equivalence of gravitational and inertial mass, i.e., of the inertial mass being the same as the 'charge' that is the source of gravity. So you do need to be careful about two masses being very close and being treated as one. Electric charges repel so not as simple, but spin 2 gravity works. Spin 0 Higgs?

Answer (score 2):

F = GM$m_1$/$R^2$ with M the mass of the earth and R the radius of the earth.  And the mass of the object is $m_1$

Let's say the mass is a few feet = h above the ground, so your distance to the center of the earth is R + h. Since h is so much smaller than R you can ignore it.

Then since F = $m_1a$, solve for a to give you

a = GM/$R^2$

That acceleration is g, the acceleration of a particle of mass $m_1$ near the surface of the earth.

Notice that it does not depend on the value of the mass of the particle, $m_1$. Thus it'll be the same for $m_2$, even if the second mass is much more massive or much less massive than the first one.

That is why g is the acceleration of any mass near the earth.

As the comment said, that is 9.8 m/$sec^2$.

A couple extra points:

1) if the masses are way higher in altitude, that is h is significant enough, g goes down some, but it's a real small difference near the surface of the earth. You can calculate it from the equations above. It is still the exact same acceleration for any two masses at the same altitude, always.

2) the above ignores the air friction. It is exact if the masses are in vacuum

3) General Relativity makes changes to Newton's equations, but for the mass of the earth the it makes a difference which is mostly unnoticeable near the surface of the earth. The differences have been  measured further out on how time can be very slightly dilated, and they agree with the theory. It is too small to make any difference for even intercontinental rockets and satellite orbits. It becomes more important for much more massive objects like neutron stars and black holes. You can ignore it in your question.

As you can se the math and the physics are very simple, and it is usually taught in high school physics. You can find simple depictions and explanations in Wikipedia

By the way, notice that the shape of the objects falling makes absolutely no difference unless you have to account for air friction (resistance). The equations then have to include the friction term, which will depend on the shape and the kind of material it is made of.

Because it depends on no property of the masses falling there is what is called the principle of equivalence: that a uniform gravitational field cannot be distinguished from a particle as seen in a uniformly accelerating frame of reference. This led to General Relativity.

Also interesting, the fact that if you are inside a satellite, and since the satellite and you have the same acceleration in space going around the earth, you seem to float inside the satellite. Otherwise you'd have to hold on just like you do in an accelerating, or worse, decelerating, car

Answer (score 0):

In absence of air resistance, the only force acting on the object is the gravitational one. We have:

$$ma=mg=G\frac{m M}{r^2}$$

Two $m$'s according to [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle) cancel. So we have something that does not include $m$.

QED

---

P.N.

-All this is because the $m$ you put in $F=GmM/r^2$ is the same as the m you use to indicate inertia of an object in $F=ma$. If these two weren't the same, we couldn't say anything.

> we [...] assume the complete physical equivalence of a gravitational field and a corresponding acceleration of the reference system.
>       — Einstein, 1907